# how to point to a pointer pointing to a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays

create a dynamic array

```
int testSize = 10;
float *spec = new float[testSize];
```

how do you point to spec which points to the dynamic arary?
I tried this but It didn't work.

```
float **specPtr;
*specPtr = &spec[0];
```

Comment: Use `specPtr = &spec;` instead of `*specPtr = &spec[0];`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that by putting the dereference operator operator, you're assigning what the pointer `specPtr` points to, not what it actually is.

Try this instead

```
float **specPtr;
specPtr = &spec; // Note the omission of the '*'
```

Comment: This is wrong. The right hand side is equal to `spec`, and you cannot assign a `float*` to `float**`.

Answer (score 0):

```
float **specPtr;
specPtr = &spec;
```

spec is a pointer,so spePtr is the pointer that point to spec